# Is possible to open and display both front and back cameras simultaneously?

Tags: camera

Does anyone know if it is possible to open and display both front and back cameras simultaneously?
Any suggestions or references will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to these two answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377081/access-both-back-and-front-cameras-simultaneously and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227768/how-to-save-front-and-back-camera-footage-in-the-same-file-after-being-recorded

According to the first answer, most often the android phone do not have enough hardware resources to have both camera working at the same time.

However, this is quite old answer and these days phones come with much better hardware support. You can try opening front camera while the rear camera is in action.

Hope this helps.